# TypeScript type annotation for res.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm using typescript for my app `node.js` express.
I would like say the `res.body` is type personne.
I have tried this:

```
router.post('/',(req: Request, res: Response) => {
   const defunt:PersoneModel = res.(<PersoneModel>body);
}
```

I have this model:

```
export type PersoneModel = mongoose.Document & {
  nom: String,
  prenom: String,
}
```

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We can use `as`. This should be enough to imply that `res.body` is `PersoneModel`

```
 const defunt = res.body as PersoneModel;
```

However more straightforward way is declaring type of the variable as a `PersoneModel`

```
 const defunt: PersoneModel = res.body;
```

Comment: Though this may have been the preferred course at the time, I would recommend using Express's built-in generics over this solution, noted in @onoya's answer.

Answer (score 121):

**Update:**

As of `@types/express@4.17.2`, the `Request` type uses generics.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L107

```
interface Request<P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

You could set the type of `req.body` to `PersoneModel` like this:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

router.post('/',(req: Request<{}, {}, PersoneModel>, res: Response) => {
   // req.body is now PersoneModel
}
```

---

For `@types/express@4.17.1` and below

Encountered similar problem and I solved it using generics:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

interface PersoneModel extends mongoose.Document {
  nom: String,
  prenom: String,
}

interface CustomRequest<T> extends Request {
  body: T
}

router.post('/',(req: CustomRequest<PersoneModel>, res: Response) => {
   // req.body is now PersoneModel
}
```

Comment: Great!

How can I type this by using the RequestHandler type?

Comment: Neither of these work for me. For `req: Request<{}, {}, PersoneModel >` I get the error "Type Request is not generic" and for `interface CustomRequest<T> extends Request` I get the error "Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null'". Using @types/express ^4.17.9.

Comment: Same as @Ash, I am using 4.17.11.. not sure how anyone can make this work

Comment: @Ash & @Peroxy - are you importing the `Request` type from `express`? It could be that TypeScript is inferring the `Request` type from the `Fetch API`.

Comment: For those interested, I've got a working example in a sample project up here: https://github.com/BeyondCodeBootcamp/jsdoc-typescript-starter

Comment: By using `{}` as type you overwrite former type such as `ParsedQs`. Is there a way to preserve them without mentioning them explicitly?

Comment: If I do this and receive a request with only some fields specified, the rest of fields are populated with undefined. Is there a way to avoid this? Because those undefined fields are typed as optional. Thank you in advance

Comment: @JakubOrsula , I found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71858480/how-to-make-typescript-type-annotation-for-res-body-without-overwriting-the-orig/71858629#71858629

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me (I am using node, express, and a postgres Pool connection):

```
import express, { Response, Request } from 'express';

export interface ITeamsRequest {
  teams?: ITeam[];
  divisions?: ITournamentDivision[];
}

export function setupTeams(app: express.Application, client: Pool) {
  app.get(
    '/teams',
    async (req: Request, res: Response<ITeamsRequest>) => {
        const teams = // get teams;
        const divisions = // get divisions;
        res.status(200);
        return res.json({ teams, divisions });
    },
  );
}
```

The key thing is to manually import Request and Response, and using a type generic (`Response<ITeamsRequest>`) you can define your own ResBody type.

This was on express version 4.17.1 and @types/express 4.17.11

Answer (score 2):

```
router.post('/',(req: Omit<Request,'body'> & { body: PersoneModel }, res: Response) => {
   // code
}
```

this also will do, useful if you want to create abstration

Comment: be careful when lifting interfaces from req, because an IUser might have 'admin' flag that someone could inject in the req body so that you lift the flag.

Comment: IUser and Injection? Need more clarification