# convert object into interface Object typescipt

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express, backend

I am new in typescript and working on a project.
I am trying to build a rest API and I have one model for my request payload.

But after typecasting as well type of the reObj is still object and I want it to be a requestObj type

```
 export const funcName = async function (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) {

        console.log(typeof req.body)  // object
        const resObj : requestObj  =  req.body as requestObj 
        console.log(typeof resObj)  // object.     but it should be requestObj
```

```
export interface requestObj {
    to:  string ,
    name: string,
    phoneNo : string, 
}
```

Because of this data is not getting validated at all.
I have search a lot but not able to find any soultion.

Comment: The `Express.Request` type supports generics to define the `body` type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55413670/14357

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript file, and JavaScript doesn't have any type named `requestObj`. All objects have type `object`. And in TypeScript all types exist only before compiling. If you want to check types within TypeScript you should use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) because using javascript's 'typeof' won't help you.

Comment: requestObj is the name of interface not any type.
what i want is to cast obkect into any interface type if it can.