# How to make TypeScript type annotation for req.body without overwriting the original Request Type in Express?

Tags: typescript, express

I can do something like below to set the type of req.body to PersoneModel.

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

router.post('/',(req: Request<{}, any, PersoneModel>, res: Response) => {
   // req.body is now PersoneModel
}
```

However, I overwrite the original Request Type such as `P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary` shown below.

```
interface Request<P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
```

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import `ParamsDictionary` from `express-serve-static-core` like below.

```
import { ParamsDictionary } from "express-serve-static-core";
import { Request, Response } from 'express';


router.post('/',(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, PersoneModel>, res: Response) => {
   // req.body is now PersoneModel
}
```