# Is there an alternative for res.json body type from the "any" type to a specific type in express using Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, types, web-development-server

I am trying to simply change the body type in the res.json() function that is currently set to the "**any**" type by default in express while using TS. As prompted below in the tooltip this is what it is.

`Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>.json: (body?: any) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>`

I'll set up a controller function example here to kind of show what I am trying to do here:

```
const sampleController: RequestHandler = (req, res) => {
  res.status(500).json({
    status: "error",
    message: "This route does not exist.",
  });
};
```

In the `.json()` function I am wanting to set the body to a specific type such as this:

```
interface JsendData {
  status: string;
  message: string;
  results: number;
}
```

Therefore an example of the tooltip above would then look like this afterwards (This is what I am trying to set it to look like rather..):

`Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>.json: (body?: JsendData) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>`

Considering this is what I am trying to do, I HAVE found a simple solution by simply going into `node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core` path and fill in my JsendData type in the line below that is found in the file.

`export type Send<ResBody = any, T = Response<ResBody>> = (body?: any) => T;`

replacing the "any" inside the function parameter to "JsendData" like this..

`export type Send<ResBody = any, T = Response<ResBody>> = (body?: JsendData) => T;`

(But for some reason this doesn't feel as if it's the best solution, I mean unless, it's a normal practice to do it this way? Idk.)

However, I am trying to figure out if there is a better alternative of doing this instead of the above steps of having to go through manually changing it like this?

I thought at first I could just type-cast my JsendData type like this in the `.json()` function:

```
const sampleController: RequestHandler = (req, res) => {
  res.status(500).json({
    status: "error",
    message: "This route does not exist.",
  } as JsendData);
};
```

but the problem I then am running into is that considering the body type in the `.json()` function is still of the "any" type, this way kind of works when it comes to TS knowing what are the properties in the obj., BUT no error will prompt in this case for a missing property for example. For that to work is when I HAVE to replace the "any" type to my Type in the express declaration file manually as I had presented above.

I hope I was able to explain this thoroughly well to see what would be the best way of getting this problem I am going through resolved.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript type annotation for res.body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027563/typescript-type-annotation-for-res-body)

Comment: I have already come across that, but unfortunately not..

Comment: Doesn't `res: Response<JsendData>` work?

Comment: The type for the body when still applying it like this is still inferred to as any. It still works but in terms of getting the type support fully its not there..